# How can I block a function in a DLL from exporting?

Tags: c++, dll

I want to export just one function from a DLL:

```
extern "C" int __stdcall DoSomething(int &inputSize, int &outputSize);
```

it exports great with a nice name. But all other functions from this DLL also exports- except with ugly names.

Can I block them from exporting?

I use this tool to see what is exported:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a definition file. This is the exact use case it was created for.

```
;     @Author : Brandon.
;
;     @param  : MyDLL Definition File.
;     @param  : Another Description.


LIBRARY MyDLL
DESCRIPTION "MyDLL Definition File"
EXPORTS

DoSomething;
```

Save as `MyDLL.def`

Now it will export the function call "DoSomething".

To use it with Mingw/Codeblocks you have to add:

`-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup`
`-Wl,--kill-at -d --input-def src/MyDLL.def`

to the linker flags. Visual Studio does it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

What you are interested in, is the visibility of the symbols. In gcc and clang, by default all symbols are exported. You can use `-fvisibility=hidden` as a command switch.

gcc also has attributes you can use to set the visiblity of a particular symbol:

```
#define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define DLL_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
```

Comment: I have a lots of functions here so marking every one of them with __attribute__ is a pain. So I tried this -fvisibility=hidden with my MinGW but it didn't do anything.